# Por que, no Angular, usamos interrogação?

Tags: angular

Porque no Angular usamos interrogação, por exemplo:

```
*ngIf="listaxpto?.clientes.length"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O `?` é um [operador](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) do Angular que protege a propriedade contra valores nulos e indefinidos.

No seu caso, sem o uso do operador e o objeto `listaxpto` sendo `null` seria lançado uma exceção

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientes' of null.

mas em alguns casos é necessário iniciar a propriedade com valor `null`